# delete gesture does not recognize the click to delete the item

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

There are no error messages, but when I click on Delete button the delete gesture does not recognize the click and does no delete the selected content.

I do not find and understand the problem, can you help me find the error please ?

This is the confirm dialog function to delete

```
Future<dynamic> customDialogDel(BuildContext context, Task task) {
    return Get.dialog(Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: Get.height * 0.35, horizontal: Get.width * 0.18),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      width: Get.width * 0.8,
      height: Get.width * 0.8,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Delete Task!',
                  style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text(
                  'Are you sure?',
                  style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 40),
                Container(
                  width: 140,
                  child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Get.back();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                              child: Text(
                                'No',
                                style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                border: Border.all(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              )),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            // slideC.activeState?.close();
                            Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                            deleteTask(task);
                            Get.back();
                          },
                          child: Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
                              child: Text(
                                'Yes',
                                style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
                                ),
                              ),
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              )),
                        )
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

and this is the page where the user can click delete, a dialog box appears asking for confirmation, but when the user clicks yes, the content is not deleted:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: Get.height,
        width: Get.width,
        color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 50),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 25, right: 25),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'All Tasks',
                    style: kSubHeadTextStyle.copyWith(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(
                      // FontAwesomeIcons.history,
                      FontAwesomeIcons.clockRotateLeft,
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Get.to(() => PastTasksView());
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Get.height * 0.012),
            GetBuilder<HomeController>(
              id: 1,
              builder: (controller) {
                return Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final task = controller.commingTasks[index]!;
                      return Slidable(
                        // actionPane: SlidableBehindActionPane(),
                        // actionExtentRatio: 0.2,
                        // controller: controller.slideC,
                        child: ExpandedContainer(
                          icon: task.taskImage,
                          title: task.taskTitle,
                          time: task.startTime,
                          desc: task.taskDesc,
                          ifDate: true,
                          date: DateFormat.yMMMd().format(task.taskDate!),
                        ),
                        startActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: BehindMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                              onPressed: (context) {
                                // controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                                Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                controller.preUpdateTask(task);
                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                  isScrollControlled: true,
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) {
                                    return BottomSheetContent(
                                      buttonText: 'Update Task',
                                      onSubmit: () {
                                        controller.updateTask(task);
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                ) as IconData;
                              },
                              label: "Update",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        endActionPane: ActionPane(
                          motion: BehindMotion(),
                          children: [
                            SlidableAction(
                              onPressed: (context) {
                             //   controller.slideC.activeState?.close();
                                Slidable.of(context)?.close();
                                controller.customDialogDel(context, task);
                              },
                              label: "Delete",
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: controller.commingTasks.length,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these kinds of cases I recommend you to do:

```
flutter clean && flutter run
```

It worked out for me most of the time. If it does not let me know.

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't work